# Cannot key in bearer api token into Postman Santau.io api

Tags: python, api, postman

The below link is the santau.io api documentation.

https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/6411292/TVev3iy5

I am using python code. However, if I type the code below, I could not extract the data as expected. The weird thing is that it does not show how to key in the bearer api token into the code to get authorized for extracting the data. Anyone have experience to deal with it?

**Updated code**

```
import requests

url = "https://santau.io/api/v1/histories?name=3A&start_date=2019-08-13&end_date=2020-08-15&limit=100&offset=0"

api_token="B67KqyJstY4SLrf4......" #not real API token, just an example

payload={}
headers ={"Authorization": "Bearer " + api_token}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

After you register http://santau.io/register, you can get API token.

[image]

Then you put it to header to make a request.

Comment: Ya, I have define *api_token* as the API token I get from santau.io in string format.  The problem is when I put headers ={"token": api_token} , I still could not able to extract financial data. Instead the python code lead me to the registration page of santau.io

Comment: No. Bearer token will be config like this `headers ={"Authorization": "Bearer " + api_token}`